# Symfony override fos user bundle templates

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override fosuserbundle default template.

I did just like in docs.

1) Created new bundle placed at `src/UserBundle`

2) Created new bundle *class UserBundle.php* at `src/UserBundle/UserBundle.php` which *return FOSUserBundle name*

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

3) Placed all *FOSUserBundle* templates in next directories and edited them.
`src/UserBundle/Resources/views/ChangePassword`
`src/UserBundle/Resources/views/Group`
`src/UserBundle/Resources/views/Profile`
`src/UserBundle/Resources/views/ChangePassword`
etc..

I still see default templates. I have cleared the cache.

Do i missed something?

Comment: Did you register your UserBundle in AppKernel.php?

Comment: If all you want to do is override the FOSUserBundle tamplates you can replicate the directory structure in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views` rather than creating a whole new bundle just for the template files.

Comment: qooplmao, i will override controller too

Comment: hm, it cant find my class. new AppBundle\UserBundle() in AppKernel.php